# QToolButton::setIcon causes memory leak, what's wrong?

Tags: qt, memory-leaks

The code looks like this:

```
QPixmap result (16, 16);
ui->m_btnInfo->setIcon(result);
```

Where m_btnInfo is a `QToolButton`. These 2 lines are called in a loop, and every consequent call leaks some small, but noticeable amount of memory. Since this is called several times a second - I get quite a leak. It looks as though the previously set icons are not disposed.

Ideas anyone?..

P. S. Windows, Qt 4.7.3.

**Update:** It doesn't leak in a simple loop, it leaks if I make those two lines of code a slot and trigger it with a timer.

P. P. S. Qt 4.8.0 - still leaks.

Comment: I too have experienced memory leaks in Qt 4.7. There is no guarantee that the underlying libraries (Qt or third party) correctly manage the memory. Just how much leak do you get??

Comment: Try to create a minimal example , eg a simple widget that contains just a QToolButton and these two lines that are called in a loop. If the memory leak is present then you should issue a Qt bug report. If not then the memory leak occurs somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @webclectic: good point. I reproduce the problem with new empty project and just a toolbutton. Interesting thing, though - it doesn't leak within a plain loop, but it leaks if I trigger it with a timer.

Comment: Can you show all the code for the simple example that leaks?

Comment: @DustyCampbell: Sure, here it is: https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/secure/attachment/26930/LeakTest.zip

Comment: How are you detecting the leak?

Comment: @DustyCampbell: I observe the amount of memroy consumed by the process.